# How can I get the ð symbol with TIPA?

Tags: tipa

According to the description, `\dh` should do the trick -- but although TIPA is installed and although `\textbeta` and `\textgamma` show up just fine, `\dh` produces an error:

> "Command `\dh` unavailable"...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you need the `fontenc` package? Detexify says it should be `\dh` and that worked for me, with or without `tipa`

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
    \dh
\end{document}
```

[Link to Detexify for reference](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

Comment: I have TIPA but not FONTEC... I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The `tipa` package will give you `\dh` but only within an IPA environment (either `textipa{\dh}` or `\begin{IPA}` ... `\end{IPA}`).  Independently of this, the `[T1]` encoding (plus a font that has the relevant glyph) will enable `\dh` without loading `tipa` at all (but obviously not other phonetic characters.)

Comment: `tipa` loads `fontenc` internally. If you are going to load it manually you should use the `noenc` option when loading `tipa`, like it says in section 3.1.1 of the documentation. But in any case `\dh` should be available even outside `textipa` and the `IPA` environment (it is _Input 1_); within `tipa` you can use `D` and that's enough: `\textipa{D}`