# Writing English phonetic symbols when using a different language package

Tags: symbols, languages, linguistics

I'm writing a document in Spanish language, and I'd like to introduce English phonetics for some words. Is it possible to do so?

I've tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    /fəˈnɛtɪk/
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work.

---

I've retaken this to make some tests but it's not working for me.
I'm using the preamble provided by egreg's answer but I'm having the error `\select@language{spanish}`
How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you know about the `tipa` package?

Comment: I know, but I mixed it with the Spanish and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show a non working example? It will make easier to find a way to help you.

Comment: @egreg See my updated question.

Comment: @egreg Can you see my updated question?

Comment: Please, open a new question with the details. However, it can just be a matter of removing the aux file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use UTF-8 characters for the phonetic symbols, you have to teach them to LaTeX, because the `tipa` package doesn't provide support for this. Alternatively, you can input them with the shorthands provided by the package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ˈ}{"}
\newunicodechar{ə}{@}
\newunicodechar{ɛ}{E}
\newunicodechar{ɪ}{I}

\begin{document}

\textipa{/fəˈnɛtɪk/}

\textipa{/f@"nEtIk/}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to extend the set of supported characters? Let's see, for instance,

```
ˌjuːnɪˈvɜːsɪtɪ
```

I added `\textipa{/ˌjuːnɪˈvɜːsɪtɪ/}` to the example above and, upon running `pdflatex`, I saw the errors

```
Unicode char ˌ (U+2CC) not set up for use with LaTeX

Unicode char ː (U+2D0) not set up for use with LaTeX

Unicode char ɜ (U+25C) not set up for use with LaTeX
```

Then I went to the manual of `tipa`, Appendix A *Annotated List of TIPA Symbols* and looked for the characters, just like I did for the previous ones. The last one appears like in the image below

[image]

so I know what shorthand to put in the second argument to `\newunicodechar`.

Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tipa}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ˈ}{"}
\newunicodechar{ə}{@}
\newunicodechar{ɛ}{E}
\newunicodechar{ɪ}{I}
\newunicodechar{ˌ}{""}
\newunicodechar{ː}{:}
\newunicodechar{ɜ}{3}

\begin{document}

\textipa{/ˌjuːnɪˈvɜːsɪtɪ/}

\textipa{/fəˈnɛtɪk/}

\textipa{/f@"nEtIk/}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\newunicodechar` you could use

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{025C}{3}
```

instead of `\newunicodechar{ɜ}{3}`, but I find it more convenient to have the “real” character instead of its code point.

Comment: I'm having trouble to write `/ˌjuːnɪˈvɜːsɪtɪ/`, how can you do this?

Comment: @Ustanak I also added the general method for extending the set.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX, you shouldn't have any trouble using the Unicode symbols directly in your `.tex` file. See [Typesetting phonetic symbols: Unicode or tipa?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224164/typesetting-phonetic-symbols-unicode-or-tipa) for a list of reasons to do this instead of using `tipa`.

This MWE will work fine if you don't load `polyglossia` and set the default language to Spanish, but doing so will load language-specific hyphenation, punctuation, and spacing patterns (`polyglossia` is the XeLaTeX counterpart of `babel`).

With `fontspec`, you can load any system font that has the symbols you need, so feel free to replace Charis SIL with one you have on your system.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
\noindent Puedo escribir en español.\\
\noindent [ˈpweðo eskɾiˈβiɾ en espaˈɲol]
\end{document}
```

[image]