# Correct typesetting of phonetic alphabet and sounds

Tags: xetex, unicode, polyglossia, tipa, phonetic

I'm writing a small article that includes a section about Greek, Arabic and Hebrew phonetic alphabet and sounds.

After reading [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304284/adding-complex-phonetic-symbols-to-latex), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224164/typesetting-phonetic-symbols-unicode-or-tipa) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300012/writing-english-phonetic-symbols-when-using-a-different-language-package), it's a bit blurry on what the *best practice* is to add phonetic alphabet and sounds to a LaTeX document? That is, a solution that provides the phonetic symbols, markers, layout etc., but also how to mark/highlight each sound (e.g. `/l/`) in the text (rather than typing in forward slash and including a character that represents a sound).

Packages like [tipa](https://ctan.org/pkg/tipa?lang=en), [fontspec](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec?lang=en), [newunicodechar](https://ctan.org/pkg/newunicodechar?lang=en), [polyglossia](https://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia?lang=en) are (maybe) part of the answer, but which (combination/approach) is best practice?

*Typesetting using XeLaTeX, document class `memoir` and with packages `polyglossia`.*

Comment: Interesting question, although it is a bit broad and opinion-based at the moment. I would suggest that you start with `tipa`, write a small document with a sentence or two where you want to add phonetic symbols, markers, layout, then add as much of the phonetic information as you can using `tipa` and other methods that you might think of, then ask how you can add the missing elements and/or how you can improve the input of the elements that you have using concrete examples.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You have several questions posed here, some of which are really duplicates. To summarize what I've said in my answers to the questions you linked to: what I consider best practice is to enter Unicode phonetic symbols directly into the `.tex` code (using an IPA keyboard overly or an online IPA picker), load a system font that has your symbols using `fontspec`, and compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I always recommend *against* using `tipa` unless there's a compelling reason to use it.

Comment: The subquestion that is *not* a duplicate as far as I know is how to create a macro for the slashes that surround phonemic transcriptions. It's not hard to do, but if that's what you're interested in, it would be best for you to edit your question to focus on that, and include a Minimal Working Example that could be adapted by someone answering the question to show you how to add the macro.

Comment: Following @JasonZentz 's comment, if phonetic symbols are considered as a script, the more general question becomes: "How do I input *any* script?" ആСТОПɃɐɭǖɲȥ The secondary question of "Which packages should I use to process a document written that way?" is the tail on the metaphorical dog and is constrained by one's compilation environment: if a more modern and powerful toolchain is unavailable or unobtainable, use a fallback one (and then choose whether to have an upgrade path or not - sometimes a complete re-write is more efficient than continual grinding using stone-age methods :)).