# Can I add an English word pronunciation automatically using latex?

Tags: tipa, english, pronunciation

I know that there's a package named tipa that could handle the phonetic symbols gracefully and manually. I want to know if there's a way to input those phonetic symbols automatically based on a word, for example, I want to know the word "explanation" pronunciation without a dictionary, how can I accomplish that using latex?

Comment: So to make it clear, you're looking for a LaTeX package that translate though → /ðəʋ/, tough → /tʌf/, through → /θru/, and trough → /trɒf/?  This is difficult (if not impossible?) without some sort of dictionary.  You'd be better of finding an external program or service that does that (which I would bet uses an internal dictionary anyway)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Maybe I will try if an internal dictionary will resolve that problem. Do you know any dictionaries work in combination with Texwork or Texmaker?

Comment: I don't know of any package that can do that, and I doubt there are any.  I would look for a program to do that, or probably just do it manually.  Curiously, why can't you just use tipa and input the IPA pronunciation manually?

Comment: There's nothing in LaTeX that can take an English word and give you an IPA transcription, but if you have transcriptions from an electronic dictionary, you wouldn't have to convert IPA transcriptions into `tipa` format. You can use them in the Unicode format they would already be in. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224164/42880.

Comment: A solution would be to use `sys_shell_now` to invoke external program such as espeak to get the IPA then parse the output (of course you have to implement it yourself)