# Redefining IPA glyphs without tipa

Tags: fonts, unicode, tipa, mathpazo

I am preparing a paper containing a few IPA characters to submit to a journal and would like to find glyphs that match the font of the journal. The ones generated by `tipa` don't match:

[image]

And from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224164/typesetting-phonetic-symbols-unicode-or-tipa#240621) discussion I gather that `tipa` is considered a legacy method anyways and we should be moving away from it.  The [template](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex) of the journal uses `mathpazo` fonts, which, I believe, doesn't have those glyphs.

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % I believe fontenc and inputenc are not needed 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % anymore but the journal template still has them 

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ʃ}{\textesh}
\newunicodechar{ʤ}{\textdyoghlig}
\newunicodechar{ʧ}{\textteshlig}

\begin{document}    
ʃ  t  ʧ  d  ʤ 
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to define a different glyph for ʃ, ʤ, and ʧ, preferably without using `tipa`, that matches the `mathpazo` font (I believe it is Palatino)?

Comment: There are several IPA fonts available from SIL: https://www.sil.org/linguistics/linguistics-software I don't know whether any of them might match the `mathpazo` font, but the available fonts are solid, and definitely usable with LaTeX.

Comment: If the template requires you to use `pdflatex` and won't allow you to use a UTF8 engine like `xelatex` or `lualatex` then you are pretty much stuck with using TIPA, since I don't know of other IPA fonts that are usable with `pdflatex`. Since I suspect they won't let you change, then TIPA is what you should use even if it's much more designed to match with Computer Modern.  The fonts @barbarabeeton mentions are open type fonts that aren't really usable with `pdflatex`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, the template requires `pdflatex`, unfortunately.  I use `xelatex` for my own needs, normally, so haven't run into this issue.  So aside from `tipa` there's no font package that includes ipa characters?

Comment: Not that I’m aware of.

Comment: There is Domitian, which has T3 encoded fonts, but just a few glyphs. The family LinguisticsPro has full support, but the font is based on Utopia, see [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDcZC.png) The “d” is passable, for the t one could think to move the standard t closer to the esh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use LinguisticsPro, at least of the “strange” glyphs and make the ligatures by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\newunicodechar{ʃ}{\textesh}
%\newunicodechar{ʤ}{\textdyoghlig}
%\newunicodechar{ʧ}{\textteshlig}
\newunicodechar{ʤ}{d\kern-0.22em\textyogh}
\newunicodechar{ʧ}{t\kern-0.18em\textesh}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{ppl}{LinguisticsPro-LF}

\begin{document}

Text in Palatino abcdef

ʃ  t  ʧ  d  ʤ

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a perfect solution, thanks so much!   I'm curious about the `\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution` macro – I couldn't find any documentation on that. Could you expand on how it works?  (why don't I have to load `\usepackage{linguisticspro}` for example?)

Comment: @jan You find it in `ltnews.pdf`